# Object is not getting removed properly from Array list

Tags: java, android, arrays

```
     ICheckBoxClick icheckBoxClick = new ICheckBoxClick() {

        @Override
        public void onCheckCliked(boolean isChecked,String pkgName,int pos) {
        String packageName = cat_name+","+pkgName;
        AppModel appmodel = new AppModel();
        appmodel.pkgName = packageName;
        appmodel.dbId = 0;
           if( isChecked ) {
             selected.add(appmodel);
           } else{
             selected.remove(appmodel);
           }
        }
    };

    appsGrid.setAdapter(new AllAppsSelectionAdapter(actityCtx,icheckBoxClick));
     Button addItems = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.add_applications);
     addItems.setOnClickListener( new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
          iAddSubItemsClick.addClicked( selected );
          dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
```

what is wrong in above code ? Based on isChecked am adding and removing objects into and from respectively to arrayList. But on clicking on OK button am still able to see objects present in it.seems like object is not getting removed properly.

Comment: Without knowing what the `selected` collection is (List? Set?) I'm going to guess that the equality conditions aren't being met by what's in the `selected` collection and the `AppModel` object you build. Do you have an `equals` method for the `AppModel` class?

Comment: selected in an ArrayList

Comment: public class AppModel {
 public String pkgName = null;
 public long dbId = 0;
 
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should overrides `equals` and `hashCode` method in your AppModel class.

Here is how the `remove` method works:

> removes the element with the lowest index **i** such that **(o==null ? get(i)==null : o.equals(get(i)))** (if such an element exists).

Answer (score 1):

Here is the wrong in your lines..

```
    AppModel appmodel = new AppModel();
    appmodel.pkgName = packageName;
```

here you are creating a new `Object` and adding or removing..if the `isChecked` is false you are creating a new `object` and performing remove operation.but that newly created object is not added so far..you are removing the object which is not in the list..thats why it is not removing..

check like this and remove..

```
     else{
           for (AppModel amodel  : selected) {
            if (model.pkgName.equals(packageName)) {
                selected.remove(model);
                break;
            }
          }   
       }
```

Comment: But still am not clear Even though I created an object , I haven't added it into an ArrayList if isChecked is false!

Comment: Cool got the concept.

Comment: ok..Arraylist is collection of Objects..you can perform remove opearion only if the same object is added to arralist..here you are creating new object using new opeartor but you are added different object..so object wont remove..

Answer (score 0):

After deletion or addition of item, notify that data set has been changed. 
yourAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged() function does this.